# I can't get Json object attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

I'm using JS to do some function in my webpage and I have backend function giving me this JSON

```
{ "id": 1, "name": "First Like", "description": "Like at least 1 page", "image": "images/badges/FIRST_LIKE"}
```

So I learned how to get those attributes with jQuery, I can get "name" and "description" but somehow I can't get "image" attribute which I need to add to url to call image href. This is my JS function:

```
jQuery(function($){

    $.getJSON('http://eclipsewildflyserver-gobanit.rhcloud.com/something/id=1',
      function (data) {
        var name=data.name;
        var description=data.description;
        var image=data.image;

        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name.toString();
        document.getElementById("description").innerHTML=description.toString();
        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=image.toString();
    });
});
```

It's not giving me any error or something. Just won't get the "image" attribute.

Comment: Typo in `("image").innetHTML`, should be `("image").innerHTML`

Comment: Yes, sorry for that mistake, but its not it. I will fix that to not distract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tag `image` you need to use `src` attribute:

```
document.getElementById("image").src = image;
```

And you don't need to call `toString()` function, it's already `String`

---

See working example:

```js
var data = { "id": 1, "name": "First Like", "description": "Like at least 1 page", "image": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"};

var name=data.name;
var description = data.description;
var image = data.image;

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = description;
document.getElementById("image").src = image;
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="description"></div>
<image id="image"></image>
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't help... its still underlining me  the "var image=data.image;"

Comment: @M.Redy I've just tried your url `http://eclipsewildflyserver-gobanit.rhcloud.com/something/id=1`, it was response `Not Found` check your `url`

Comment: I didnt upload full url here, but it works.  The JSON answer from it is exactly what i wrote upthere

Comment: { "id": 1, "name": "First Like", "description": "Like at least 1 page", "image": "images/badges/FIRST_LIKE", "thresholds": [ { "id": 1, "count": 1, "sumCount": 0, "activityType": { "id": 1 } } ], "rank": { "id": 1 }, "group": { "id": 1 } }

Comment: I think your problem is with image, try to test it `document.getElementById("image").src = "your path to image";`

Comment: Okay, so... the url wont work. Is there any chance I can take out that atribute just as string? like the name and description ?  because the part
var image=data.image; still gives me error "Unresolved type"

Comment: @M.Redy I've made working example, everything is working, your error in something else, check your `json` and `image path`